# Can 'Understood' be used here?

Tags: word-usage

If someone tells you an instruction/order, can you answer with 'Understood', rather than 'I understand'? I felt like I heard that being used, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: You probably could however I can only imagine someone saying understood, if they are in the army or talking to someone who is of high power like a general or something. If you are talking to your friend and you say "understood" that sounds a bit odd imo

Answer (score 1):

> "Be sure to clean up after yourself."
>   "Understood."

In this exchange, *understood* is not being used as a short form of *I understand*. Instead, it's being used as a short form of something else.

> "✘ (I) underst(and)."
>   "✔ (It is) **understood**."
>   "✔ (I have) **understood**."

The full version of the sentence is assumed to exist, even though it's not actually being spoken. Either of the full versions will work in the context.

---

Similarly, I hear kitchen staff shouting "*Heard!*" in response to head chefs reciting orders. (At least that's what I've heard on cooking shows on TV.)